# Angular.module minification bug

Tags: javascript, angularjs, minify, uglifyjs

Having the darnedest time trying to figure out why minification is not working.

I have injected via an array object my providers prior the function per numerous suggestions across the web and yet still "Unknown provider: aProvider <- a"

Regular:

```
var app = angular.module('bpwApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ui', 'myTabs'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {templateUrl: 'partials/home.jade', controller: HomeCtrl});

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }])
```

Minified:

```
var app = angular.module('bpwApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ui', 'myTabs'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function(a, b){
    a.
        when('/', {templateUrl: 'partials/home.jade', controller: HomeCtrl});

    b.html5Mode(true);
    }])
```

Any suggestion would be much obliged!

Comment: What do you use to minify your code? uglifyJS? Also check out: https://github.com/btford/ngmin ;)

Comment: I used ngmin, all it did was line up the code in a different white space format. I tried using express-uglify as middleware but it was not working so I tried manually using an online uglifier. Either way the code ended up the same.

Comment: Also, isn't there a missing ````]```` ? (before the closing ````)```` )

Comment: There was, I forgot them in this particular snippet. It does not change the fact "unknown provider a" still happens :(

Comment: Ok, well, what online minifier did you use? This works fine with your code: http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/uglifyjs

Comment: It minifies the code dandily. That is what I used.

The issue is once it runs it says it is not written appropriately and cannot find the provider "a"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32172/discussion-between-bpwdevelopment-and-andrem96)

Comment: [Using uglify and minify together][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24215002/2371560

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AndrewM96 suggestion of `ng-min` is right.

The alignment and white space matters to Uglify as well as Angular.

Comment: [ng-min](https://github.com/btford/ngmin#conceptual-overview) appears to just process the angular files so they are friendly to `uglify`. In our build process we use both (`ng-min` before `uglify`) and still had an issue with the uglified js.

Comment: Why is this marked as the answer? (Also, AndrewM96 should be AndreM96)

Comment: though in docs ng-min sounds promising it does not solve the problem

Comment: @craigb having the same problem. Maybe it's a combination of things. I use RequireJS as well. I basically do all the function-changing-stuff ng-min should do myself and still run ng-min, than run require build and than run uglify with mangle true.
This process seems to work most of the times.

Answer (score 139):

I ran into this problem before with Grunt.js [**Uglify**](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify) plugin.

One of the options are **[mangle](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify#mangle)**

```
uglify: {
  options: {
    mangle: false
  },
```

Which I believe runs regex functions on "like strings" and minifys them.

For example:

```
angular.module("imgur", ["imgur.global","imgur.album"]);
```

Would become:

```
angular.module("a", ["a.global","a.album"]);
```

Disable it --- this feature doesn't play nice with Angular.

### Edit:

To be more precise as @JoshDavidMiller explains:

Uglify `mangle` only mangles like variables, which is what actually causes the AngularJS problem. That is, the problem is in injection and not definition.

`function MyCtrl($scope, myService)` would get mangled to `function MyCtrl(a, b)`, but the service definition inside of a string should never get altered.

- Running `ng-min` before running `uglify` solves this problem.

Comment: He updated his code. His problem wasn't that "$locationProvider" became "b" or anything like that. It just didn't work. However, +1 for this answer :)

Comment: I ran into this exact same thing when using angular bootstrap + yeoman. Using the [yeoman angular generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular) it produced a `dist` build that would have the mentioned dependency error "Unknown Provider". Setting `mangle: false` solved the problem. (note: the issue was only a problem in the `grunt` built `dist` not the developer friendly `app` build)

Comment: Does `mangle: true` *really* mangle "like strings"? I'm pretty sure it only mangles like *variables*, which is what actually causes the AngularJS problem. That is, the problem is in injection and not definition. `function MyCtrl($scope, myService)` would get mangled to `function MyCtrl(a, b)`, but the service definition inside of a string should never get altered. Running `ng-min` before running `uglify` solves this problem, no?

Comment: `ng-min` is now deprecated in favor of [`ng-annotate`](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate)

Comment: I do not recommend to set mangle to true. Insead of check what angular sey about the error: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05#a-note-on-minification. That worked for me in quite a large Angular app.

Answer (score 51):

## Problem

From [AngularJS: The Bad Parts](http://larseidnes.com/2014/11/05/angularjs-the-bad-parts/):

> Angular has a built in dependency injector that will pass appropriate
>   objects to your function based on the names of its parameters:
>
> ```
> function MyController($scope, $window) {
>     // ...
> }
> ```
>
> Here, the names of the parameters `$scope` and `$window` will be
>   matched against a list of known names, and corresponding objects get
>   instantiated and passed to the function. Angular gets the parameter
>   names by calling `toString()` on the function, and then parsing the
>   function definition.
>
> The problem with this, of course, is that it **stops working the
>   moment you minify your code**. Since you care about user experience
>   you will be minifying your code, thus using this DI mechanism will
>   break your app. In fact, a common development methodology is to use
>   unminified code in development to ease debugging, and then to minify
>   the code when pushing to production or staging. In that case, this
>   problem won’t rear its ugly head until you’re at the point where it
>   hurts the most.
>
> (...)
>
> Since this dependency injection mechanism doesn’t actually work in the
>   general case, Angular also provides a mechanism that does. To be sure,
>   it provides two. You can either pass along an array like so:
>
> ```
> module.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$window', MyController]);
> ```
>
> Or you can set the `$inject` property on your constructor:
>
> ```
> MyController.$inject = ['$scope', '$window'];
> ```

## Solution

You can use [`ng-annotate`](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) for auto adding annotations required for minifying:

> `ng-annotate` adds and removes AngularJS dependency injection
>   annotations. It is non-intrusive so your source code stays exactly the
>   same otherwise. No lost comments or moved lines.

`ng-annotate` is faster and stabler than [`ngmin`](https://github.com/btford/ngmin) (which is now deprecated) and it has plugins for many tools:

- [`grunt-ng-annotate`](https://github.com/mzgol/grunt-ng-annotate)
- [`gulp-ng-annotate`](https://github.com/Kagami/gulp-ng-annotate)
- [`browserify-annotate`](https://github.com/omsmith/browserify-ngannotate)

---

Starting from AngularJS 1.3 there's also a new param in [`ngApp`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp) called **`ngStrictDi`**:

> if this attribute is present on the app element, the injector will be
>   created in "strict-di" mode. This means that the application will fail
>   to invoke functions which do not use explicit function annotation (and
>   are thus unsuitable for minification), as described in the [Dependency
>   Injection guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di), and useful debugging info will assist in tracking
>   down the root of these bugs.

Comment: +1 Simply switching to grunt-ng-annotate fixed this issue and ngmin is deprecated now anyway so that's another reason to switch.

Comment: that was the fix I was looking for days!

Comment: I am facing the same problem building a minified code with browserify, angular and gulp-minify. I have removed gulp minify and replaced it by gulp-ng-annotate, code is still minified but still doesn't work.

Comment: @BigDong if you're using browserify the best way is probably to enable `ngStrictDi` (something like `<div ng-app="myApp" ng-strict-di />`) and use `gulp-ng-annotate` even in your in your development environment so that you easily track down these minification bugs.

Comment: @PaoloMoretti I did try with ngStrictDi and gulp-ng-annotate, browserify can bundle but code isn't minified, isn't it supposed to be ng-annotate job ?

Comment: I create my controller like that : .controller('SomeCtrl', ['$scope', function SomeCtrl ($scope) 

After looking inside the bundle.js file, I can't see any change by gulp-ng-annotate, so i have just removed the plugin

Comment: We use MyController.$inject = [<dependencies>] but still it doesn't work. I wonder what the issue could be! We even use ng-annotate without success. Is there something else that can be causing this?

Comment: @Willa make sure that the dependency you're trying to load is actually included in the minified bundle.

Comment: @PaoloMoretti sorry for a late response. We still have this problem. Actually we are loading all dependencies just fine. I even examined the minified version of all the files and I see the controller is there defined and registered with angular. I even tried to disable mangling of the variable but still I can't get the minified version of the app to work.

Answer (score 22):

I got same error. However, for me, the problem is directives' controller declaration. You should do this instead.

```
myModule.directive('directiveName', function factory(injectables) {
    var directiveDefinitionObject = {
      templateUrl: 'directive.html',
      replace: false,
      restrict: 'A',
      controller: ["$scope", "$element", "$attrs", "$transclude", "otherInjectables",
        function($scope, $element, $attrs, $transclude, otherInjectables) { ... }]
    };
    return directiveDefinitionObject;
  });
```

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/3125

Comment: Thank you @angelokh ! I had exactly this problem. I was using the `controller: function ($scope) {}` notation.

Comment: This is more like the solution to the actual problem than `mangle: false` suggested in other responses, because we still want to be able to mangle names.

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar issue using grunt, ngmin and uglify.

I ran the process in this order: concat, ngmin, uglify

I was continuing to get the $injector error from angular until I added in the uglify options mangle: false - then everything was fixed.

I also tried to add the exceptions to uglify like this:

```
 options: {
  mangle: {
     except: ['jQuery', 'angular']
  }
}
```

But to no avail...

Here is my gruntFile.js for further clarification:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
'use strict';
// Configuration goes here
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: require('./package.json'),

    watch: {
        files: ['scripts/**/*.js', 'test/**/*spec.js', 'GruntFile.js'],
        tasks: ['test', 'ngmin']
    },

    jasmine : {
        // Your project's source files
        src : ['bower_components/angular/angular.js', 'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js', 'scripts/app.js', 'scripts/**/*.js' ],
        // Your Jasmine spec files

        options : {
            specs : 'test/**/*spec.js',
            helpers: 'test/lib/*.js'
        }
    },

    concat: {
      dist : {
          src: ['scripts/app.js', 'scripts/**/*.js'],
          dest: 'production/js/concat.js'
      }
    },

    ngmin: {
        angular: {
            src : ['production/js/concat.js'],
            dest : 'production/js/ngmin.js'
        }

    },

    uglify : {
        options: {
            report: 'min',
            mangle: false
        },
        my_target : {
            files : {
                'production/app/app.min.js' : ['production/js/ngmin.js']
            }
        }
    },

  docular : {
      groups: [],
      showDocularDocs: false,
      showAngularDocs: false
  }

});

// Load plugins here
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-ngmin');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-docular');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jasmine');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');

// Define your tasks here
grunt.registerTask('test', ['jasmine']);
grunt.registerTask('build', ['concat', 'ngmin', 'uglify']);
grunt.registerTask('default', ['test', 'build', 'watch']);
```

};

Comment: AH THANK YOU THANK YOU! that has saved me so much time.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. And solved it the following way. We need to run a Gulp module called gulp-ng-annotate before we run uglify. 
So we install that module

```
npm install gulp-ng-annotate --save-dev
```

Then do the require in Gulpfile.js

```
ngannotate = require(‘gulp-ng-annotate’)
```

And in your usemin task do something like this

```
js: [ngannotate(), uglify(),rev()]
```

That solved it for me.

[EDIT: Fixed typos]

Comment: gulp-MG-annotate should be gulp-NG-annotate?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the mistake. Where reads `mg-annotate` is always `ng-annotate`

Answer (score 2):

Uglify has an option to disable mangling on specific files:

```
options: {
  mangle: {
     except: ['jQuery', 'angular']
  }
}
```

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify#reserved-identifiers

Comment: adding 'angualr' didnt fix the problem. It is not a preset.

Answer (score 2):

This is very difficult to debug because a lot of services are named the same (mostly e or a). This will not solve the error, but will **provide you with the name of the unresolved service** which enables you to track down, in the uglified output, the location in the code and finally enables you to solve the issue:

Go into `lib/scope.js`of Uglify2 (`node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/scope.js`) and replace the line

```
this.mangled_name = this.scope.next_mangled(options);
```

with

```
this.mangled_name = this.name + "__debugging_" + counter++
```