# Building angular app with grunt, app fails to load

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

I have generated an angular project with yeomon (yo angular). I did some coding and tested if I could build the project (with grunt) properly. Result came out in the dist folder and it worked perfectly. Now I've coded some more (about 1000 rows) and I once again built the project. This time the browser shows nothing. No error in console. Index.html is correct and the minified js-files also seems ok.

I've added a proxy in Gruntfile.js otherwise I don't think I've done anything with it.

Any idea what can be the cause of this? How do I debug this most efficiently? Only way I can think of is to deactive everything and then acitvate module, build project, activate one more and so on. Will take a lot of time.

**Update**
I've narrowed it down. I have a few resolves. If I remove them, then the view loads. I'm using ui-router. Can this be to any more help to resolove the issue?

```
.state('app', {
        url: '/app',
        resolve: {
          //medias: ['MultiProductsLoader', function(ProductsLoader) {
          //  return new ProductsLoader();
          //}]
        },
        views: {
          'inputView': {
            templateUrl: 'views/input.html',
            controller: 'AppCtrl'
          }
        }
```

**Update2**
My question was a bit unclear. The app worked perfectly when the project was in "develop mode", unminified. But when I built/minified the project, the app failed to laod without any error message. Se answer below for the solution.

Comment: Are you using Chrome Dev Tools?

Comment: @coma yes, shows nothing

Comment: If there is no error in the Chrome console maybe you just disabled the javascript...

Comment: this view exists in the ui-view? like ui-view="inputView"?

Comment: @Deividi Cavarzan Yes.

Comment: and this app state is a separated module? If was, check if you import the module correctly in your main js app file.

Comment: are you using `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` ?

Comment: @Illan Frumer, tried, no luck

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved!

I added this to the uglify options in Gruntfile.js

```
  options: {
    report: 'min',
    mangle: false
  }
```

You can read more about it here were I found the answear: [Angular.module minification bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17238759/angular-module-minification-bug)

Comment: Ok! That worked for me too but maybe you could provide some summary explaination about your solution. The link you suggest is very full of many solutions. Why did this work?

Answer (score 0):

If a resolve cannot be resolved by ui-router, then the view(s) defined in the state will not be rendered, resulting in an empty page (or empty part of a page depending on the state).

When I encounter such a problem, I disable all resolves (by commenting them out) in the state hierarchy and re-enable them one by one to see which one causes the problem and then add some logging inside the resolve callback to see what's happening.

Ui-router is awesome but it is still under development and this is one area where more debugging info would indeed be welcome.

Hope that helps!