# Error after Minification of angular js. Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: eProvider <- e <- makeErrorsDirective

Tags: javascript, angularjs, minify, bundling-and-minification, gulp-minify

I used Gulp to minify my entire js files. Once minified I got an error like  the following:

```
[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: eProvider <- e <- makeErrorsDirective.
```

---

I had a Custom directive in my controller file.

```
var myhubdashboardControllers = angular.module('vpdashboardmodule', []);

.directive('mhDashboard', function ($http, authService, apiService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            name: '@',
            dash: '@',
            report: '@',
            disname: '@',
            disdesc: '@',
            distot: '@'
        },
        templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/dashboard-direc.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            scope.linkChk = scope.name;
            switch (scope.linkChk) {
                case 'Shipped This Week':
                    scope.url = 'erp/JobShipmentList/PostCpsVwShipmentCount';
                    scope.shipstatus = "Departure";
                    scope.period = "ThisWeek";
                    scope.basicfilter = "Open";
                    scope.linkName = "Shipments";
                    scope.linkDesc = "Shipped This Week";
                    break;
```

})
};

This is the code used in my application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angularjs minification using grunt uglify resulting in js error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22866183/angularjs-minification-using-grunt-uglify-resulting-in-js-error)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is a reason why you have to inject services and controller in string array.

if you want to inject scope to controller, you have to use

```
angular.module('yourApp')
    .controller('yourController',['$scope',function($scope){
    }]);
```

Minification will change the variable names and if you don't use that array of strings while injecting services or controllers, it will be like

```
 angular.module('yourApp')
    .controller('yourController',function(e){
    });
```

So, angular will not be able to understand what 'e' stands for, hence the error. 
Always remember that the order is also important.

```
.directive('mhDashboard', ['$http','authService','apiService', function ($http, authService, apiService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            name: '@',
            dash: '@',
            report: '@',
            disname: '@',
            disdesc: '@',
            distot: '@'
        },
        templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/dashboard-direc.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            scope.linkChk = scope.name;
            switch (scope.linkChk) {
                case 'Shipped This Week':
                    scope.url = 'erp/JobShipmentList/PostCpsVwShipmentCount';
                    scope.shipstatus = "Departure";
                    scope.period = "ThisWeek";
                    scope.basicfilter = "Open";
                    scope.linkName = "Shipments";
                    scope.linkDesc = "Shipped This Week";
                    break;
}
}])
```

Comment: i had a custom directive in my controller file.after minification it produces the error like   [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: eProvider <- e <- e directive..Other than that everything working fine.

Comment: thanks Raghu. I done for controller but i missed for directives. It works now.

Comment: Had the same issue, I had to use the `["$http", function ($http) { ... }]` syntax on my services & directives as well as my controllers. Thank you for pointing this out. +1'd

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue, even when I use gulp-ng-annotate, but it only happens occurs for $stateProvider and ngDialog resolves:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('orders', {
    url: '/orders',
    templateUrl: 'templates/orders.html',
    controller: 'OrdersController as vm',
    resolve: {
      authenticate: function (Auth) {
        return Auth.getAuthResolve();
      }
    }
  });
```

Resolve needs to be written like this:

```
    resolve: {
      authenticate: ['Auth', function (Auth) {
        return Auth.getAuthResolve();
      }]
    }
```

So it feels that ng-annotate does not inject the array into resolves, but only to controller/service/factory constructors.

Comment: You should use ng-anotate everywhere that has an injection even inside resolve (before every function)

Answer (score 2):

Angular doesn't always work well with minification.

If you as an example write this:

```
angular.controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope) {...});
```

Then the `$scope` would be changed to something meaningless during minification.

If one instead changes that to:

```
angular.controller("MyCtrl", ["$scope", function (s) {...}]);
```

Then it doesn't matter what the first argument in the function is called (here `s`), as long as the string is `"$scope"`.

See this: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05#a-note-on-minification in the documentation for more details.

If you want more help, you have to post the code in question, not just the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue using `angular-ui-router-title`. After changing

```
$titleProvider.documentTitle(function($rootScope) {
    return $rootScope.$title + ' my title';
});
```

to

```
$titleProvider.documentTitle(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    return $rootScope.$title + ' my title';
}]);
```

the error doesn't appear anymore.