# Angular Controller Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, uglifyjs

I am trying to uglify my AngularJS Code. I followed all the tutorials on the internet an have now the following code but I am still getting and error after uglifying:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngMaterial', 'pascalprecht.translate', 'ngSanitize', 'material.components.expansionPanels', 'ngFileSaver', 'ngMessages', 'ngFileUpload', 'ngStorage']

TestController.$inject = ['$scope', '$translate', '$timeout','$mdSidenav', '$log', '$sessionStorage'];

angular.module('myapp').controller('TestController', TestController);

function TestController ($scope, $translate, $timeout, $mdSidenav, $log, $sessionStorage) {}
```

Edit:
I have found the problem. The problem was I configurated the module with:

```
app.config(function ($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

Rather than:

```
app.config(['$locationProvider', function ($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);

app.directive('onReadFile', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: false,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var fn = $parse(attrs.onReadFile);

            element.on('change', function(onChangeEvent) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function(onLoadEvent) {
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                        fn(scope, {$fileContent:onLoadEvent.target.result});
                    });
                };

                reader.readAsText((onChangeEvent.srcElement || onChangeEvent.target).files[0]);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Is the name of your module `myapp` (all lower case) or `myApp` (camel case)?

Comment: Syntax is not an issue here!

Comment: Considering you have an issue with the injector...it is.  There's not quite enough information here to say beyond a shadow of a doubt what it is; could you show us what services you depend on in your module?

Comment: I have just edited it. You can now see the dependencies!

Comment: Could you also add the *exact* error you're getting after the code?  It's tough to say *which* module is going awry here.

Comment: Do you get an error minifying it if you exclude the controller? Help narrow down where exactly the problem is.

Comment: Yes I do! Oh then it probably is the module which causes the error!

Comment: Double check that you have zero errors concerning your dependencies before trying to minify.

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: Is everything running ok before you try and uglify your code? i.e. you can run it and you get zero errors in the console?

Comment: Sorry for that stupid question! I found the error! But I have another issue. Can we have a chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123459/discussion-between-user2085143-and-thigi).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Always try and make sure your app is running correctly before trying to uglify the code.

Same as you were doing with the controller, when setting up your directives use the same approach where you use $inject to declare the dependencies.

See below

```
app.directive('onReadFile',onReadFile);

onReadFile.$inject = ['$parse'];

function onReadFile($parse){

  var directive = {
    restrict:'A',
    scope: false,
    link: link
  }

  return directive;

  //////////

  function link(scope, element, attrs){

      var fn = $parse(attrs.onReadFile); 

      element.on('change', function(onChangeEvent) { 

        var reader = new FileReader(); 

        reader.onload = function(onLoadEvent) { 
          scope.$apply(function() { 
            fn(scope, {$fileContent:onLoadEvent.target.result}); 
          }); 
        }; 

        reader.readAsText((onChangeEvent.srcElement || onChangeEvent.target).files[0]); 
      }); 

  }// end link

}// onReadFile
```

Comment: The function is hoisted already and doesn't really do anything until Angular invokes it, so I'm not 100% convinced it's declaration order...

Comment: @Makoto but order could be important if we want to uglify.

Comment: @valverde93:  No, order isn't important.  Again, the fact that the function is declared as `function ...` will hoist it within its scope, so it's going to be made readily available.

Answer (score -1):

Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22866183/angularjs-minification-using-grunt-uglify-resulting-in-js-error).

Try using it this way:

```
angular.module('myapp').controller('TestController', ['$scope', '$translate', '$timeout','$mdSidenav', '$log', '$sessionStorage', function checkInCtrl ($scope, $translate, $timeout, $mdSidenav, $log, $sessionStorage){}]);
```

Comment: Both forms of dependency injection are valid and equivalent, and would survive uglification.

Comment: Somehow my form does not survive it! @Makoto