# Grunt build causing Angular app to crash on dist

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, bundling-and-minification

I am using Grunt and executing cmd "grunt build" to create a distribution folder containing an AngularJS app.

As a standalone my app is working fine. Once I create a distribution for the app the app starts to crash pretty quickly.

I am seeing in F12 Tools Console is:

**10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!**

I am suspicious of a file in my .tmp directory called vendor.js and a failure to minify, uglify and or concat this file correctly because of controller dependency injection variables mangling injected controller arguments like "$scope" to "a" for example, even though I am using ngAnnotate.

See I am using UglifyJs and calling ngAnnotate before Uglify and Concat but I cannot remove UglifyJs from useMinPrepare or I have other errors such as the scripts directory not even being created in my dist directory:

```
useminPrepare: {
  html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
  options: {
    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
    flow: {
      html: {
        steps: {
          js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
          css: ['cssmin']
        },
        post: {}
      }
    }
  }
},
```

I am setting mangle = false in my GruntJs file but I am suspicious of useMinPrepare `js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs']` changing the sequence of execution and running uglify before ngAnnotate can run when `useMin` is called, even though I call `useMin` after `ngAnnotate`.

I am new to Grunt and this app has been passed to me from another developer.

I found this article that doesn't exactly make sense to me and also isn't a code change that seems to apply to my Gruntfile.js but I thought maybe I was on to something:

https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack/issues/164

**I have set the Uglify mangle option to false but it has not fixed my issue.**

Here is my Gruntfile.js code:

```
  module.exports = function (grunt) {

    // Load grunt tasks automatically
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
    require('time-grunt')(grunt);

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-connect-proxy');

    // Define the configuration for all the tasks
    grunt.initConfig({

    // Project settings
    yeoman: {
      // configurable paths
      app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
      dist: 'dist'
    },

    // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
    watch: {
      bower: {
        files: ['bower.json'],
        tasks: ['bowerInstall']
      },
      js: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/**/*.js'],
      //        tasks: ['newer:jshint:all'],
        options: {
          livereload: true
        }
      },
      html: {
            files: ['**/*.html'],
            options: {
                livereload: true
            }
        },
      jsTest: {
        files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
        tasks: ['newer:jshint:test', 'karma']
      },
      compass: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
        tasks: ['compass:server', 'autoprefixer']
      },
      gruntfile: {
        files: ['Gruntfile.js']
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
        },
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
          '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
        ]
      }
    },

    // The actual grunt server settings
    connect: {
      options: {
        port: 9000,
        // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
        hostname: '0.0.0.0',
        //hostname: 'localhost',
        livereload: 35729
      },
      proxies: [{
        context: ['/api', '/images'],
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 60878,
        changeOrigin: true
      }],
      livereload: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          base: [
            '.tmp',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>'
          ],
          middleware: function (connect, options) {
            var middlewares = [];

            if (!Array.isArray(options.base)) {
              options.base = [options.base];
            }

            // Setup the proxy
            middlewares.push(require('grunt-connect-proxy/lib/utils').proxyRequest);

            // setup push state
            middlewares.push(require('grunt-connect-pushstate/lib/utils').pushState());


            // Serve static files
            options.base.forEach(function(base) {
              middlewares.push(connect.static(base));
            });

            return middlewares;
          }
        }
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          port: 9001,
          base: [
            '.tmp',
            'test',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>'
          ]
        }
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          middleware: function (connect, options) {
            var middlewares = [];

            if (!Array.isArray(options.base)) {
              options.base = [options.base];
            }

            // Setup the proxy
            middlewares.push(require('grunt-connect-proxy/lib/utils').proxyRequest);

            // setup push state
            middlewares.push(require('grunt-connect-pushstate/lib/utils').pushState());

            // Serve static files
            options.base.forEach(function(base) {
              middlewares.push(connect.static(base));
            });

            return middlewares;
          }
        }
      }
    },

    // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
    jshint: {
      options: {
        jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
        reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
      },
      all: [
        'Gruntfile.js',
        '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
      ],
      test: {
        options: {
          jshintrc: 'test/.jshintrc'
        },
        src: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js']
      }
    },

    // Empties folders to start fresh
    clean: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          dot: true,
          src: [
            '.tmp',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
          ]
        }]
      },
      server: '.tmp'
    },

    // Add vendor prefixed styles
    autoprefixer: {
      options: {
        browsers: ['last 1 version']
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
          src: '{,*/}*.css',
          dest: '.tmp/styles/'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Automatically inject Bower components into the app
    bowerInstall: {
      app: {
        src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
        ignorePath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/'
    //        ,exclude : ["bower_components/angular-snap/angular-snap.css"]
      },
      sass: {
        src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
        ignorePath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components/'
      }
    },

    // Compiles Sass to CSS and generates necessary files if requested
    compass: {
      options: {
        sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
        cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
        generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
        imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
        javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
        fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
        importPath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components',
        httpImagesPath: '/images',
        httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
        httpFontsPath: '/styles/fonts',
        relativeAssets: false,
        assetCacheBuster: false,
        raw: 'Sass::Script::Number.precision = 10\n'
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          generatedImagesDir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/generated',
          fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts'
        }
      },
      server: {
        options: {
          debugInfo: false
        }
      }
    },

    // Renames files for browser caching purposes
    rev: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          src: [
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
    //            ,'<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
          ]
        }
      }
    },

    // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
    // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
    // additional tasks can operate on them
    useminPrepare: {
      html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
      options: {
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
        flow: {
          html: {
            steps: {
               js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'], 
              css: ['cssmin']
            },
            post: {}
          }
        }
      }
    },

    uglify: {
        dist: {
           options : {
            report: 'min',
            mangle : false
           // compress: false,
           // beautify : true
        }
    }
  },

    // Performs rewrites based on rev and the useminPrepare configuration
    usemin: {
      html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
      css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
      options: {
        assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>', '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts', '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images' ]
      }
    },

    concat: {
      options: {
        separator: grunt.util.linefeed + ";" + grunt.util.linefeed
      }
    },

    // The following *-min tasks produce minified files in the dist folder
    //    cssmin: {
    //      options: {
    //        root: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
    //      }
    //    },

    imagemin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    svgmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.svg',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    htmlmin: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
          removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
          removeOptionalTags: true
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: ['*.html', 'scripts/{,*/}*.html'],
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
      }
    },

    // ngmin tries to make the code safe for minification automatically by
    // using the Angular long form for dependency injection. It doesn't work on
    // things like resolve or inject so those have to be done manually.
    ngAnnotate: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/concat/scripts',
          src: '*.js',
          dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts'
        }]
      }
    },

    ngtemplates: {
      fctrs: {
        cwd: "<%= yeoman.app %>",
        src: ['scripts/**/*.html'],
        dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts/templates.js'
      }
    },

    // Replace Google CDN references
    cdnify: {
      dist: {
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html']
      }
    },

    // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
    copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: [
            '*.{ico,png,txt}',
            '.htaccess',
            '*.html',
            'views/{,*/}*.html',
            'images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
            'styles/fonts/*',
            'statics/**',
            'test_data/**/*.json'
          ]
        },
        {
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/images',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
          src: ['generated/*']
        }]
      },
      styles: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
        dest: '.tmp/styles/',
        src: '{,*/}*.css'
      }
    },

    processhtml: {
        options : {
            commentMarker : "process"
        },
      dist: {
          files: {
              '<%= yeoman.dist %>/index.html':['<%= yeoman.dist %>/index.html']
          }
      }
    },

    // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
    concurrent: {
      server: [
        'compass:server'
      ],
      test: [
        'compass'
      ],
      dist: [
        'compass:dist',
        'imagemin',
        'svgmin'
      ]
    },

    // Test settings
    karma: {
      unit: {
        configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
      }
     }
    });


    grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
      return grunt.task.run(['build', 'configureProxies:server',     'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
      'clean:server',
      'bowerInstall',
      'concurrent:server',
      'autoprefixer',
      'configureProxies:server',
      'connect:livereload',
      'watch'
    ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('server', function (target) {
    grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
    grunt.task.run(['serve:' + target]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'clean:server',
    'concurrent:test',
    'autoprefixer',
    'connect:test',
    'karma'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'bowerInstall',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'concat',
    'ngAnnotate',
    'ngtemplates',
    'copy:dist',
    'cdnify',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'rev',
    'usemin',
    'processhtml',
    'htmlmin'

  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'newer:jshint',
    'test',
    'build'
  ]);
};
```

Comment: [Angular requires that when you minify, do not "mangle"](http://google.com/search?q=angular+mangle)

Comment: Run `grunt serve:dist`, this will spin up a test server from the dist folder so you can see if the error occurs outside of the app you're moving it to.

Comment: Yes I am having the same error with grunt serve:dist

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17238759/angular-module-minification-bug

Comment: You should add a `ng-strict-di` attribute on your `<html>` tag to force Angular to crash if a dependency wasn't properly annotated. This way you'll at least see if that's what's causing your issue and target the problem more easily.

Comment: In my case, ng-strict-id would instantly cause Angular to crash as many of of my controllers are not properly annotated. But if you see what the error turned out to be in my answer, it is still a mystery to me why this error would only occur when building a dist and did not occur with grunt serve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I went down the wrong path thinking smoothing was wrong with Uglify or concat or minification.

The error did not occur with `grunt serve` but did occur only after a dist package was created with `grunt build:dist`

So it was deceiving in a sense that my Angular app DID work fine until I created a dist package.

The issue was for me, that I originally had a `<ng-include src="'scripts/navigation/navigationMobile.html'"></ng-include>` element in my Index.html file.

At some point I created a custom element directive `<my-nav></my-nav>` which used the same `templateUrl = scripts/navigation/navigationMobile.html` but I forgot to remove the `<ng-include src="'scripts/navigation/navigationMobile.html'"></ng-include>` element from my Index.html that `<my-nav></my-nav>` was intended to replace.

For whatever reason the **10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!** only occurred after running `grunt build` and creating the minified, Uglified vendor.js file, it did not occur when just developing and testing using `grunt serve` but I do not know the exact reason that the error only presented itself after `grunt build`.

**Maybe someone can answer that.**

Answer (score 1):

I noticed we need to give a hint to ng-annotate in two cases:

- Subclassing (ES6 class) when super class has injectables on constructor and sub class has no constructor;
- $get method of a provider

Error in digest check is occurring from a task that only runs in `grunt build`, or is related to you creating a directive from an ng-include.

When you change from ng-include to have it as your directive's template, angular will suspend compilation until the next digest, when template is eventually loaded, even when it is already in $templateCache.

Reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile (see templateUrl)

As a final note, I'd have take a look on ngtemplates because it avoids requests over the wire, and angular compiles templates out-of-order when they come from an external resource, it could be a bug on your implementation of that directive or any of its parents, which is not calling $compile correctly.

Answer (score 0):

> > To fix this error just open the Gruntfile.js file and add the line extDot: 'last' in both task cssmin and task uglify.

**Ex:**

```
cssmin: {
    all: {
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: srcDir,
            src: '**/*.css',
            dest: buildDir,
            ext: '.min.css',
            extDot: 'last'
        }]
    }
},
...
uglify: {
    all: {
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: srcDir,
            src: ['**/*.js', '!**/*-spec.js'],
            dest: buildDir,
            ext: '.min.js',
            extDot: 'last'
        }]
    }
},
```