# AngularJS Dependency Injection - Implicit vs Array Annotation

Tags: angularjs

So I was using this website to show me the basics: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1130132/Learn-AngularJS-for-Beginners

and on the scope inheritance section I was thrown off because of the controller used for that example compared to the example controller used as intro to controllers.

what is the difference between:

```
app.controller("PersonController", function($scope) {
    $scope.employeeData = personData;
    $scope.employeeMethod = function() {
      console.log("Hello, I am an Employee");
    }
});
```

and

```
app.controller("MainController", ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.name = "Donald"; 
    $scope.color = "White";
}]);
```

as in the first one is name then function, the second is name then bracket.

Comment: The difference is for minification. Check this out https://scotch.io/tutorials/declaring-angularjs-modules-for-minification

Comment: From the source is OP, "This way of injecting dependencies is called ‘Dependency Injection" and what @scniro said

Comment: See [AngularJS Developer Guide - Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).

Comment: See also [Angular Module Minification Bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17238759/angular-module-minification-bug)

Answer (score 0):

from [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#implicit-annotation)
implicit annotation assumes function params to be name of the services

```
someModule.controller('MyController', function($scope, greeter) {
  // ...
});
```

`$scope` and `greeter` are the names of services above.

So both DI techniques work the same way except when some JavaScript minifiers/obfuscators are used because they can rename function parameters but not the inline Array.